# Dynamically generate one model from another ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

Thanks in advance for considering my question.
I am trying to wrap my head around dynamically creating multiple table rows of one model from another as "children".
Hopefully this is not too convoluted and I will put this n the context of the "album" tutorial and Abdul Malik Ikhsan's blog on adding tracks as children (2 separate tables).
What I am trying to do is generate the tracks dynamically with a drop down in the add album action/view/form.
Basically on the add album page I have a select form field labeled "How many tracks would you like to add?" with values 1-20. So say you choose 2 in the drop down. When you click save/add you get a new album row in the album table and 2 track rows in the track table with a relationship key.
If anyone has some thoughts on how I would accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend\Form [anticipates this use-case](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html) pretty well, actually.  While the official docs don't do it the way you're saying (they expect you'll want to add new "tracks" dynamically with javascript), you can easily dumb it down.